# Very high number of HTTP Threads in WAIT state

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, tomcat, jboss

Using Java Visual VM:
I can see almost 100 Threads in WAIT state.

In JBoss Server.xml i have:

```
  <!-- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
  <Connector port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
     maxThreads="250" strategy="ms" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
     emptySessionPath="true"
     enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
     connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"/>
```

I have a ThreadPool in Jboss-Service.xml that looks like:

```
    <mbean code="org.jboss.util.threadpool.BasicThreadPool"
      name="jboss.system:service=ThreadPool">
      <attribute name="Name">JBoss System Threads</attribute>
      <attribute name="ThreadGroupName">System Threads</attribute>
      <attribute name="KeepAliveTime">60000</attribute>
      <attribute name="MaximumPoolSize">10</attribute>
      <attribute name="MaximumQueueSize">1000</attribute>
      <attribute name="BlockingMode">run</attribute>
   </mbean>
```

In Thread Dump most of threads are in following state:

```
   "http-0.0.0.0-8180-97" - Thread t@7296
       java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <23791834> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.await(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:81)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Java Visual VM also lists a very high number for Daemon Threads
Live: 176 Daemon: 171

I am using JBoxx 4x

Comment: Is this production or your dev/text env ?

Comment: How many clients are connected?  If none now, how many 'usually' connect?  it's probably just a threadPool with a pile of threads waiting on a queue for a socket object to turn up so they can start doing stuff.

Comment: Plus it's not that many, anyway.  A quick look at my box now shows 1098 threads, 'NT kernel & System':241, 'Kaspersky Anti-Virus':63 and an almost unbelievable 66 just for 'Windows Sidebar':(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a worker thread is idle, it is usually waiting on an empty queue for some new work.

I suspect these threads are waiting for more work.

Comment: +1 yes, probably waiting for some accept() thread to push on a socket object.

Comment: Peter, but where have i configured so many worker threads, or is this default value.

Comment: Usually about 50 users would be using the system.

Comment: If you have 50 users using about 2% of a thread each, then on average one thread will be busy.

Comment: @Jasper Maybe it simply doubles the number of work threads if its pool becomes empty. If you have 12 cores, maybe it started with 12, then 24, 48 and, when user 49 logged on, doubled it to 96.  Maybe.. <g> If the server is working OK, why worry?

Comment: 100, (non-ready/running) threads is next-to-nothing, anyway. At least, it is next-to-nothing on Windows. Creating 1000 waiting threads is pretty much a non-event.  I just get a big number in the 'Threads' column in Task Manager and everything else continues to perform normally.  It shouldn't be much different on any other OS.